# Manipulating website content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 questions:

1. How would I make a small overlay open if a mouse hovers over any image on a webpage?
2. How would I find selected pieces of text on a webpage and make them into a link?
   (similar to what Kontera or Vibrant does)

EDIT - Let me explain.

1. If a mouse hovers over any image on the website with a particular tag, I want a magnified version of the image opened next to it
2. If I have a word - "skills" inside my database and the webpage on which my Javascript is added has the word "skills" on it, I want it to be highlighted and linked to another page

Comment: changed your formatting to evidence the list. To me tough, the question are too general to obtain a prompt response...

Comment: If you have 2 questions, you should post 2 questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:
I know that in CSS you can use some hover keyword to effect the page (but I know little about CSS).
In javascript/HTML there is onMouseOver and onMouseOut, so.

```
<img onMouseOver="javascript:" onMouseOut="javascript:">
```

2:
You could use regex to find the text snd replace it.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new Regex("skills|other|words", g), "<a>$&</a>");  //Note that this searches inside of the html tags so it is better if you know of specific locations to search for the text instead of anywhere in the html.
```

Comment: Won't your solution to #2 unbind event listeners?

Comment: Well I have used similar before and nto encountered any trouble, but you might be right for all I know.
But I did say it would be far better if a specific location could be found to do it on instead of the whole body `document.getElementById("article")` would be far better for example.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a good javascript framework.  You can do (1) fairly easily with a host of plugins.  [Jquery Plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/05/25-excellent-jquery-image-zoom-plugins-creating-stunning-image-effects.html)

As for (2), you would probably have to do that server side.  Not sure what server technology you use, but when the view is rendered, you would have to have some sort of filter go through all the words on the page and create the links.

Comment: There's no need to have anything server-side for #2. As long as you've got an array of keywords, JavaScript can do it on its own.

Comment: @icktoofay - what exactly would be the logic for that?

Comment: @RockSalt: You have a recursive function (started with `document.documentElement`) that loops through the child nodes. If the child node is an element, it will recurse. If the child node is a text node, it looks for the keywords. If if finds an interesting keyword, it can break apart the text node and add a link.

Comment: Also There are tons of easy ways to do hover logic without JQuery. I know it is a great useful library but this question does not justify adding a it to a site or learning the syntax.